# Writing to a combobox based on a previous combobox not working

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, combobox

So I'm trying to create a calculator that works both ways to both create and look up an item number.

The first combobox, `Type`, has two columns: *[Type].[Type]* and *[Type].ID* (primary key).

The second combobox, `Chemistry`, has three columns: *[Chemistry].[ID]* (primary key), *[Chemistry].[Chemistry]*, and *[Chemistry].[Type]* (foreign key).

I have several others, but these are the ones that are causing me issues. To populate the Chemistry combobox correctly, I need to know the value of the Type combobox. This is fine when you're clicking through the comboboxes, but when I do a reverse lookup (parsing the item number to get its substituent entries). Because Type has no foreign key and doesn't populate based on any entries, it does just fine when I try to write back to the combobox. When I try to write to chemistry, the combobox doesn't populate despite having a valid entry in the Type combobox. REQUERYING AND REFRESHING DOES NOT SOLVE THE PROBLEM FOR SOME REASON. In GIF attachment, Type is Combo0 and Chemistry is Combo2. Any ideas?

Relevant Code

```
hii = Me.Text6.Value [Item Number]
v = Mid(hii, 1, 1)
w = Mid(hii, 2, 2)
vvv = DLookup("Type", "Type", "ID = " & v & "")
If w < 10 Then
www = DLookup("Chemistry", "Chemistry", "ID =" & Mid(w, 2, 1) & "")
Else
www = DLookup("Chemistry", "Chemistry", "ID =" & w & "")
End If

Me.Combo0.Value = vvv
Me.Combo2.Requery
Me.Combo2.Value = www
```

Here is the Chemistry row source:
[image]

Here is a GIF of the issue.
[image]

Comment: The code would be easier to read if you gave the comboboxes names like `cboType` and `cboChermistry` instead of `Combo0` and `Combo2`. What is the row source of the chemistry combo? Also, please insert the relevant VBA code into the question.

Comment: ^^ I edited it to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key always points to the primary key of the other table.
The `Type` foreign key column in the `Chemistry` table should correspond to the primary key `ID` in the `Type` table. I would name it `TypeID`, to make this fact clear. I assume `ID` is an Autonumber column. Then the type of `TypeID` must be Numeric/Long.

Then, of course, the Bound Column in both combos must be set so that it is bound to the respective ID.

The row source of the Chemistry combo should be something like

```sql
SELECT Chemistry.ID, Chemistry.Chemistry
FROM Chemistry
WHERE Chemistry.TypeID = Forms!Numbers!Combo0;
```

with

- Bound Column = 1
- Column Count = 2
- Column Widths = 0cm     (to hide the ID column)

You should not link or lookup the values based on `Type.Type`, which, I assume, is a text column. When you do so, the code becomes

```vb
hii = Me.Text6.Value
v = CLng(Mid(hii, 1, 1))
w = CLng(Mid(hii, 2, 2))

Me.Combo0.Value = v
Me.Combo2.Requery
Me.Combo2.Value = w
```

I tested it and it works.

You can also give the controls and variables better names. It makes the code more readable. E.g.

```vb
itemNumber = txtItemNumber.Value
typeID = CLng(Mid(itemNumber, 1, 1))
chemID = CLng(Mid(itemNumber, 2, 2))

cboType.Value = typeID
cboChemistry.Requery
cboChemistry.Value = chemID
```

is easier to read. You can also drop the `Me.`.

Comment: Wow, I named my columns very badly. *[Type].[ID]* is the primary key and *[Chemistry].[Type]* is the foreign key. I changed the bound column and I was able to write it! I need to change a little bit in the code to write from the correct column, but this solution works for me. Thank you!